# Как можно сделать ответ на событие в discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord.py

Хочу добавить в бота для *discord*, написаного на *python* (*discord.py*) событие, которое совершается при входе пользователя на сервер и выводит приветственное сообщение по типу **"Добро пожаловать! Чтобы узнать команды бота введите: !com"**. В документации я нашел как сделать подобное событие (*on_member_join*), но в этом случае нельзя выводить сообщение в чат, метод *send()* не работает.

Вот что я сделал:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    """Ввывод информации об выходе пользователя."""
    await ctx.send(f'Добро пожаловать {member}! Напиши !com чтобы узнать мои команды.')

client.run("Token") # Токен бота
```

Выходит такая ошибка:

```
TypeError: on_member_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

Как ее обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    """Ввывод информации об выходе пользователя."""
    await member.send(f'Добро пожаловать {member}! Напиши !com чтобы узнать мои команды.')
```

UPD: Если кому интересна полная реализация, она находится на моем репозитории [GitHub](https://github.com/merive/AssistBOT). Если есть вопросы, задавайте в Discussion репозитория. Буду рад если поддержите звездочкой :)

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно ссылаться на прямую к конкретному чату следующим способом:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(id чата на который ссылаешься)
    await channel.send(f'Добро пожаловать {member}! Напиши !com чтобы узнать мои команды.')
```